# MVC Model binder list Id and Name issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modelbinder

Hi I have a problem with getting correct ID's and Name when I use ajax-calls to get partials views.

I want ids like "Blocks_0__Items_0__Id" . These are rendered using for loops so
Main page:

```
@for (int blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < Model.Block.Count(); blockIndex++) {

                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Blocks[blockIndex], "BlockView")
            }
```

and then in turn the BlockView does the same list rendering for items using and editorfor.
The for loops makes the Ids and name correct.

However if I want to render the Item Template as a partial view all I will get is naturally without the Blocks and Items part.

To solve this issue I call on an empty main page that renders a block with always a single Item in it. but this means that for whatever I want to insert via ajax and readable by the modelbinder I have to create 2 extra partial views!!

Solution 2 I thought was to use the 
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix method and set that. But since I have a list withing a list tha tis not possible. I could get rid of one of the partialviews and use:
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Block"

I saw an mvc 1 and 2 Html helper called:
Html.BeginCollectionItem("nameofitem") but that does no longer exists.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using @Html.TextBox()  instead of @Html.EditorFor()

with @Html.TextBox you can pass it a name and a value

@Html.TextBox("WhateverNameYouWant", Model.Blocks[blockIndex])